# Definition of $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

In my class notes the Sobolev space is defined in a way I was unaware of. Given an open set $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^d$,

$$W^{1,p}(\Omega)=\{ u \in L^1_{\text{loc}(\Omega)} :\text{ admits weak derivative and } u\in L^p(\Omega), \nabla u \in (L^p(\Omega))^d\}.$$

I had never seen this definition, the reference for classes is also the Evans' book, which defines the Sobolev space as

$$W^{k,p}(\Omega) = \{ u \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega) : D^\alpha u \in L^p(\Omega), |\alpha| \leq k \}.$$

For the case $k=1$ are these two definitions equivalent? Why in this case is it required that $u \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$ and then $u \in L^1(\Omega)$? Maybe it's a typo and it should be $D^\alpha u \in L^p(\Omega)$.

Could anyone clarify this definition for me?

Comment: It's exactly the same for $k=1$. It is only $u\in L^1(\Omega)$ when $p=1$ (although, on bounded domains note $u\in L^p$ always implies $u\in L^1$)

Comment: One has $Du(v) = \langle \nabla u,v\rangle$ for any vector $v$, and this ensures these two definitions to be equivalent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition is correct, and the two definitions are equivalent.

However, there is another definition, also equivalent.

First set
$$
\hat C^{k,p}(\Omega)=\{u\in C^{\infty}(\Omega : \|u\|_{k,p}<\infty\},
$$
where
$$
\|u\|_{k,p}=\left(\sum_{|\alpha|\le k} \int_\Omega |D^\alpha u|^p\,dx\right)^{1/p}.
$$
Clearly, $\hat C^{k,p}(\Omega)$ is not complete, with respect to $\|\cdot\|_{k,p}$. Then $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ is the completion of $\hat C^{k,p}(\Omega)$.

A proof of the equivalence of the definitions can be found for example in Avner Friedman's PDEs.